# Is this is tick?

Tags: pests

Found this on my wall.  (I've never seen a tick before)
I live in the Northeast

[image: tick?]

Comment: Count the legs...

Comment: Ticks and spiders have 8 legs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a spider. The legs are too long and the body is segmented, apparently 2 segments in this picture. Anecdotally, although ticks are very common here, I have never seen one in a house.

Comment: I've only seen them in houses when pets (especially dogs) or people bring them in.